# Запуск приложения при включении компьютера

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть код приложения и я хочу чтобы он запускался при включении компьютера.
Однако не знаю как это правильно сделать, все что я находил в интернете не помогло, помогите пожалуйста.

Вот код приложения:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os
import random

import requests
import json
import datetime


from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QTranslator, QLocale, QLibraryInfo
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#Класс для заставки
class LoadingScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(845, 595)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.label_animation = QLabel(self)
        self.label_animation.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.movie = QMovie('tut.gif')
        self.label_animation.setMovie(self.movie)

        timer1 = QTimer(self)

        self.startAnimation()
        timer1.singleShot(4000, self.stopAnimation)

        self.show()

    def startAnimation(self):
        self.movie.start()

    def stopAnimation(self):
        self.movie.stop()
        self.close()





class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окна
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setWindowTitle('Unapp')
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
        #Вызываем класс с заставкой
        self.loading_screen = LoadingScreen()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)


        
        #Кнопка с домиком(главной страницей)                                 
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Кнопка с заметками
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('калькулятор.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #кнопка с калькулятором
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        #Кнопка с текстовым редактором
        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

               
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))


        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
#1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        fontleo = QFont('Century Gothic', 25, QFont.Bold)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
#Ленин виджет с пожеланиями
        #self.leo = Example()
        
        
        #self.leo.setParent(self.page_1)






#календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 380))
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(Calendar_StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)


        #self.main = App()

        #self.main.w_root.setParent(self.page_1)
        #self.main.w_root.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430,0,345,153))
        

        #self.main.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
        #self.main.move(455,0)
        

        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setKerning(True)

        #self.CAL = Calculator(
            #title='Calculator App : Made by Rahul',
            #parent=None,
            #uiFile='form/ui_calculator.ui')
        #self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.CAL.window)  


        

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #336699;')
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        #Заметки
        #self.view = AppView()

        
        # instance of the controller
        #self.ctrl = AppController(view=self.view)


        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)

        #self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.view)

        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        #Текстовый редактор
        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(12)
        font2.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        #self.gg = Main()
        #self.gg.setFont(font2)


        
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               


        #self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.gg)




        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')


       


        
        
       
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
# verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
# verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
    #Функция для добавления приложения в автозапуск Windows
        def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
            if file_path == "":
                file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % (USER_NAME)
            with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
                bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "r") as bat_file:
                _file = bat_file.read()    
            print(_file)
     #Функция для показа текущего времени
    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

Calendar_StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: #6d86a4;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6d86a4;
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;  
    image: none;              
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: #6d86a4; 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Иконка_Горы.png'))
    app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    PATH_LANGUAGE = r'C:/python2/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations/qtbase_ru.qm'
    translator = QTranslator(app1)
    translator.load(PATH_LANGUAGE, "ru_RU")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно проверять наличие только что запущенного скрипта в папке автозагрузки, и если его там нет - копировать туда.

```
import os, sys

Thisfile = sys.argv[0] # Полный путь к файлу, включая название и расширение
Thisfile_name = os.path.basename(Thisfile) # Название файла без пути
user_path = os.path.expanduser('~') # Путь к папке пользователя

if not os.path.exists(f"{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{Thisfile_name}"):
        os.system(f'copy "{Thisfile}" "{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"')
        print(f'{Thisfile_name} добавлен в автозагрузку')
```

Но это будет работать только в случае, если у вас программа собрана в **.exe**
В противном случае, вам помимо самой программы, в папке автозагрузки нужно будет создать **.bat** или **.cmd** файл, который уже будет запускать скрипт в интерпретаторе.

```
@echo off
python PythonCode.py
exit
```

Comment: Я скомпилировал python файл в exe и при включении компьютера у меня появляется ошибка **Порядковый номер 380 не найден в библиотеке dll**.
Из-за чего может быть эта ошибка?

Comment: @ivapop, я не знаю, могу разве что посоветовать погуглить или посмотреть здесь: https://mywebpc.ru/windows/poryadkovyj-nomer-ne-najden-windows-10/

Answer (score 3):

Для начала откройте рабочий стол, нажмите сочетание клавиш Win + R, затем у Вас должно открыться окно "Выполнить", где Вы должны прописать "shell:startup". У вас откроется папка с автозагрузками, куда Вы должны добавить файл с кодом. Надеюсь, что я смог помочь. .

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/633682)

Comment: Понял, то есть мне нужно изменить этот комментарий?

Comment: Изменить ответ, да. Чтобы он содержал ответ

Comment: Теперь тут есть ответ, как Вам? Буду благодарен за +рейтинг.

Comment: ссылку могли оставить как источник ) вы первый, кто обратил внимание на замечание

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, перейдя к папке с вашим исполняемым файлом, нажать Win + R, ввести shell:startup, нажмите ОК. Таким образом откроется папка Автозагрузки. Создайте там ярлык вашего файла

Comment: А можно ли сделать автозапуск с помощью кода?

Answer (score 0):

Разве не будет проще вбить задачу через "Планировщик задач Windows"?
Является самым лёгким способом